# windows store app in C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

This might be very newbie, I am experienced asp.net and c# developer with winforms experience as well.

I wonder what I need to learn to start making windows store app, what new technonologies, languages?

and 2nd question is:
How can I submit applications to the new windows store if its possible now?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at [the MSDN site for Metro apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/apps/br229512)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second question first.  Right now, you cannot submit applications to the Windows Store.  The OS is still in beta (consumer preview) and the store is not open to everyone.

There are many ways to program on Windows 8.  You can use JavaScript/HTML5 or you can use C#/XAML or C++/XAML.  Given your background, you should look into C# as a language with XAML as a UI framework.  This is very similar to Silverlight or WPF that you may have run across.

One good place to start is Charles Petzold's upcoming book.  It's on [sale](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145369079.do) right now.  Another place is on http://dev.windows.com.  That will point you at tutorials, reference documentation, and samples.